# For a general nonlinear ODE, does continuous dependence on a parameter imply continuous dependence on initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

If the solution of the differential equation
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y,\lambda)$$
under initial conditions $x_{0},y_{0}$, is continuously dependent on the parameter $\lambda$, does it imply that it will also be continuously dependent on the initial conditions $x_{0},y_{0}$.

I came across an argument that essentially said that the equation may be re written as 
$$\dfrac{d\alpha}{d\beta}=f(x_{0}+\beta,y_{0}+\alpha,\lambda)$$
where $\alpha =y-y_{0}$ and $\beta=x-x_{0}$. Then it was argued that the function on the right hand side is a continuous function in $x_{0},y_{0}$ and hence the solution will be. I am not able to understand how this argument holds.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this argument to make any sense, you'd have to say that the solution depends continuously on parameters "in general", not on a particular parameter in a particular differential equation.
Otherwise, you could take any differential equation you want and introduce a parameter that does nothing at all. The solution does not depend on the parameter at all, and therefore is continously dependent on it.